# Compiler error when trying to implement visitor design pattern

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I'm trying to implement the Visitor Design pattern based on a class diagram from a training material. I've been to this training a while ago and I didn't save the code I implemented there. I am stuck at a compilation error and I can't figure out what I did wrong. Most likely I didn't understood the class diagram for this design pattern. Below I put the entire code and the compilation error I received.

```
    #define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
    #include <list>
    #include "math.h"

    class Cerc;
    class Dreptunghi;
    class Arie;
    class Perimetru;
    class Operatie;

    class Forma
    {
    public:
        virtual void accept(Operatie * op);
        Forma(void){};
        ~Forma(void){};
    };

    class Cerc : public Forma {
    protected:
        int raza;
    public:
        void accept(Operatie * op){op->vizitare(this);};
        int getRaza(){return raza;};
        Cerc(void):raza(3){};
        ~Cerc(void){};
    };

    class Dreptunghi : public Forma {
    protected:
        int lungime;
        int latime;
    public:
        void accept(Operatie * op){op->vizitare(this);};
        int getLungime(void){return lungime;};
        int getLatime(void){return latime;};
        Dreptunghi(void):lungime(3),latime(3){};
        ~Dreptunghi(void){};
    };

    class Operatie{
    public:
        virtual void vizitare(Cerc* obj) = 0;
        virtual void vizitare(Dreptunghi* obj) = 0;
        Operatie(void){};
        ~Operatie(void){};
    };

    class Arie : public Operatie {
    private:
        double arie;
    public:
        double getResult(){return arie;};
        void vizitare(Cerc* obj){arie = arie + M_PI*obj->getRaza();};
        void vizitare(Dreptunghi* obj){arie = arie + obj->getLungime() + obj->getLatime();};
        Arie(void): arie(0) {};
        ~Arie(void){};
    };

    class Perimetru : public Operatie {
    private:
        double perimetru;
    public:
        double getResult(){return perimetru;};
        void vizitare(Cerc* obj){perimetru = perimetru + M_PI*obj->getRaza()*obj->getRaza();};
        void vizitare(Dreptunghi* obj){perimetru = perimetru + 2*(obj->getLungime() + obj->getLatime());};
        Perimetru(void):perimetru(0){};
        ~Perimetru(void){};
    };

    class Editor{
    private:
        std::list<Forma*> forme;
    public:
        Editor(void){};
        void insert(Forma obj){forme.insert(forme.end(), &obj);};
        double calculeazaArieTotala(){
            Arie arie;

            for(std::list<Forma *>::iterator it = forme.begin(); it != forme.end(); ++it){
                (*it)->accept(&arie);
            }

            return arie.getResult();
        };

        double calculeazaPerimetrulTotal(){
            Perimetru permietru;

            for(std::list<Forma *>::iterator it = forme.begin(); it != forme.end(); ++it){
                (*it)->accept(&permietru);
            }

            return permietru.getResult();
        };
        ~Editor(void){};
    };


    int main(void){
        Editor editor;
        cout << editor.calculeazaArieTotala() << endl;
        cout << editor.calculeazaPerimetrulTotal() << endl;
    }
```

The compiler error I get:

```
    visitordesignpattern.cpp(23): error C2027: use of undefined type 'Operatie'
    visitordesignpattern.cpp(23) : see declaration of 'Operatie'
    visitordesignpattern.cpp(23) error C2227: left of '->vizitare' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
    visitordesignpattern.cpp(23) error C2027: use of undefined type 'Operatie'
    visitordesignpattern.cpp(23) see declaration of 'Operatie'
    visitordesignpattern.cpp(23) error C2227: left of '->vizitare' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
```

Thank you!

Comment: Off-topic: I recommend using English only identifiers instead of Romanian ones (or any other language). This makes code more readable in general (just one language, not a mixture), especially in international context (like on this forum here), where some people might not understand your mother tongue...

Comment: Sorry for this, I forgot to change the Romanian names of the classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write `op->vizitare(this);`, the type of `Operatie` must be [complete](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type#Incomplete_type), i.e. the definition of it must be visible before that; only forward declaration is not sufficient.

Move the definition of `Operatie` before it. e.g.

```
... ...

class Operatie{
public:
    virtual void vizitare(Cerc* obj) = 0;
    virtual void vizitare(Dreptunghi* obj) = 0;
    Operatie(void){};
    ~Operatie(void){};
};

class Cerc : public Forma {
protected:
    int raza;
public:
    void accept(Operatie * op){op->vizitare(this);};
    int getRaza(){return raza;};
    Cerc(void):raza(3){};
    ~Cerc(void){};
};

class Dreptunghi : public Forma {
protected:
    int lungime;
    int latime;
public:
    void accept(Operatie * op){op->vizitare(this);};
    int getLungime(void){return lungime;};
    int getLatime(void){return latime;};
    Dreptunghi(void):lungime(3),latime(3){};
    ~Dreptunghi(void){};
};

... ...
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved the compilation error. I'll accept the answer as soon as the site will allow me. Why didn't the forward declaration for Operatie from the beginning of the file prevented this error?

Comment: @Sitram It's not enough. How the compiler could know whether `Operatie` has a method named `vizitare` at that point?

Answer (score 0):

Just move the definition of Operatie to the start of your code.

Answer (score 0):

There are two error in your code! as *songyuanyao* said, adjust your code arrange! the second bug is add `iostream` at the header of file! full code as below show

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <list>
#include "math.h"
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;



class Dreptunghi;
class Arie;
class Perimetru;
class Operatie;
class Cerc;

class Forma
{
public:
    virtual void accept(Operatie * op);
    Forma(void){};
    ~Forma(void){};
};
class Operatie{
public:
    virtual void vizitare(Cerc* obj) = 0;
    virtual void vizitare(Dreptunghi* obj) = 0;
    Operatie(void){};
    ~Operatie(void){};
};

class Cerc : public Forma {
protected:
    int raza;
public:
    void accept(Operatie* op){op->vizitare(this);};
    int getRaza(){return raza;};
    Cerc(void):raza(3){};
    ~Cerc(void){};
};

class Dreptunghi : public Forma {
protected:
    int lungime;
    int latime;
public:
    void accept(Operatie * op){op->vizitare(this);};
    int getLungime(void){return lungime;};
    int getLatime(void){return latime;};
    Dreptunghi(void):lungime(3),latime(3){};
    ~Dreptunghi(void){};
};



class Arie : public Operatie {
private:
    double arie;
public:
    double getResult(){return arie;};
    void vizitare(Cerc* obj){arie = arie + M_PI*obj->getRaza();};
    void vizitare(Dreptunghi* obj){arie = arie + obj->getLungime() + obj->getLatime();};
    Arie(void): arie(0) {};
    ~Arie(void){};
};

class Perimetru : public Operatie {
private:
    double perimetru;
public:
    double getResult(){return perimetru;};
    void vizitare(Cerc* obj){perimetru = perimetru + M_PI*obj->getRaza()*obj->getRaza();};
    void vizitare(Dreptunghi* obj){perimetru = perimetru + 2*(obj->getLungime() + obj->getLatime());};
    Perimetru(void):perimetru(0){};
    ~Perimetru(void){};
};

class Editor{
private:
    std::list<Forma*> forme;
public:
    Editor(void){};
    void insert(Forma obj){forme.insert(forme.end(), &obj);};
    double calculeazaArieTotala(){
        Arie arie;

        for(std::list<Forma *>::iterator it = forme.begin(); it != forme.end(); ++it){
            (*it)->accept(&arie);
        }

        return arie.getResult();
    };

    double calculeazaPerimetrulTotal(){
        Perimetru permietru;

        for(std::list<Forma *>::iterator it = forme.begin(); it != forme.end(); ++it){
            (*it)->accept(&permietru);
        }

        return permietru.getResult();
    };
    ~Editor(void){};
};


int main(void){
    Editor editor;
    cout << editor.calculeazaArieTotala() << endl;
    cout << editor.calculeazaPerimetrulTotal() << endl;
}
```

Comment: I added two objects, a `Cerc obj1` and `Dreptunghi obj2` in main and passed called `editor.insert(obj1)` and `editor.insert(obj2)`. The program crashed.

Comment: I compile it on my Mac with `g++`, and which version you have used?

Comment: I found the problem. I changed parameter `obj` of `insert()` method like this `void insert(Forma * obj){forme.insert(forme.end(), obj);};` and the calls of `insert()` from `main()` to `editor.insert(&obj1)` and `editor.insert(&obj2)` and now the program calculates the area and perimeter correctly.